# how do you "ignore" java.util.concurrent.Future objects?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Can you spot the bug?  This will throw an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestTheads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        while(true) {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

The bug is that I call `executorService.submit()` instead of `executorService.execute()`, because `submit()` returns a `Future` object I'm ignoring.  With `execute()`, this program will actually run forever.

However, one does not always have the luxury of having an `execute()` method, like when using a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this will FAIL because I ignore the ScheduledFuture object
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    while(true) {
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

What is one supposed to do with tasks that don't return anything, only compute?

Any ideas would be grateful appreciated!

**EDIT**: `ThreadPoolExecutor`s `purge()` looked promising, but it only purges cancelled tasks.

Comment: Does it work if you call `get()` on the returned `Future`? Just add `.get()` before the ending `;`. Although I suppose that would block and defeat the whole purpose of using the `ExecutorService`. You'd have to save the `Future` references, iterate over them and call `get()`.

Comment: @laz: Yeah, I think that would kinda defeat the purpose of `ExecutorService`.  Some of the workarounds I've done rely on storing and iterating, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Future` object that is returned is strongly referenced by the `ExecutorService` *only until it is executed.* (It is actually a `FutureTask` instance that delegates to your `Runnable`.) Once it has executed, it will be garbage collected, because the caller has no reference to it. In other words, the memory problem has nothing to do with the treatment of the `Future`.

If you are running out of memory, it is because the work queue has millions of tasks queued up. As with any queue, unless the average rate of consumption exceeds the average rate of production, the queue will fill up. The contents of the queue consume memory.

Use a bounded queue, which will effectively, throttle task queuing, or get more memory.

This code will run "forever":

```
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  while(true) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
      }
    });
    Thread.sleep(12);
  }
```

The difference is not in the treatment of the resulting `Future` instances, but that tasks are queued at a rate at which they can be processed.

Comment: You know, I don't know why I didn't figure that out, but you're right!  Hell, you can lower the second `Thread.sleep()` call to 5 milliseconds and it stuff runs "forever".  I would have imagined that it would have thrown a `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` or something instead.

Answer (score 7):

It's not so much the Futures that are being returned that is your problem.  The problem is, for each Runnable you submit, the ExecutorService will store them to be able to process at a later time.  Each time you invoke the submit method with a Runnable (or Future), the ExecutorService will push that runnable to a worker queue.  The Runnable will sit there until a Thread can pick that Runnable off the queue (the later time).  If all worker threads are busy then the ExecutorService will simply put the runnable to said queue.

So your problem is that you have only one thread trying to pull of a queue that is infinititely added to by another Thread.  Its being added much faster then the worker thread can process each Runnable.

Edit: The code example I gave as nos eluded to does in fact throw a RejectedExecutionException, so the mechanism for throttling would have to be slightly different if you were to choose.

As far as a better solution, like I mentioned in my comment;  If you are expecting to fill up the ExecutorService in such a way that the worker threads cannot keep up with the queue, you can serialize and deserialize requests as they come in (building your own ThreadPoolExecutor) but I would make sure the need for such a case is absolutely necessary.

Keep in mind after the work has been done those Future's will be disgarded and garbage collected. So if you do one Future per second and it executes in under a second the Future itself will be removed and you will not have a memory issue.  But if you are doing one Future a second and the threads do a Future every 3 seconds, that will draw and issue.

Edit: I profiled the heap of the program you are running and the issue is exactly that.  The FutureTask being created by the ExecutorService is sitting on the worker queue until the worker thread picks it off

```
Class Name                                                       | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor @ 0x78513c5a0            |          104 | 2,051,298,872 |     99.99% 
|- java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue @ 0x785140598        |           80 | 2,051,298,216 |     99.99% 
|  |- java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node @ 0x785142dd8|           32 | 2,051,297,696 |     99.99% 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The heap analysis goes on a bit, there are many LinkedBlockingQueue$Node's as you can imagine

Comment: You could also create a new ThreadPoolExecutor directly, passing in your own BlockingQueue(e.g. a new LinkedBlockingQueue(1000) ) constructed with a max capacity

Comment: Thank you for the response, John. Actually, this doesn't solve the issue.  Throttling does release the `Future` object from memory so it's still going to sit there.  In your example, after submitting say 2,0000 `Runnable`s, I'll still have 2,000 `Future`s in memory, so I'm back to the original problem.

Comment: @nos I like that idea better nos, Thank you!

Comment: @The Alchemist, you are correct.  The FutureTask's will forever stay in memory as long as you submit them (or a worker thread picks them off the queue and processes them).  The problem here then is you should not be submitting so many Runnables into the ExecutorService at a given time.  There is no other way for the service to know about the Runnables unless they store them in memory

Comment: The alternative is that you write your own ThreadPool which will serialize and deserialize  requests.

Comment: @John V. Although, with handing in a BlockingQueue with a max capacity, I believe you'll get a RejectedExecutionException by default when you try to submit() more tasks than the queue' capacity, though this can be customized by providing a RejectedExecutionHandler (that e.g. just puts the task onto the queue again in a blocking fashion)

Comment: @The Alchemist this is the problem. Having 2000 Runnables in memory isn't a problem, but your example code will create many many millions of runnables within seconds that arn't immediatly executed, and that's causing the OOM - you have to trottle a busy loop submitting tasks. (Once the tasks have been executed, they'll be available for garbage collection, but until they're executed, they stay in memory)

Comment: @nos: It's only proof-of-concept code.  A million objects in one second, or one object per second for an entire week, the point is that `Future` objects sit around in memory forever.  There's many workarounds, but I was wondering if there was a good, clean way to handle this.

Comment: @The Alchemist as my recent edit notes - If the Future is being processed fast enough you will never have the memory issue.  That is, a thread will pull the Future off the queue, call its run method and return.  This will get rid of the Future and it will no longer be in memory.

Comment: @The Alchemist: The `Future` will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the task run has been run, so no it won't sit around in memory forever.

Comment: @nos, @John V.: Turns out I was wrong in my initial conclusion.  It's not that `Future` objects aren't getting cleaned up but that the `Executor` can't run them quickly enough, ColinD and erickson have pointed out.

Comment: That's what I have been saying from the beginning :)